# Best Windows XP Budget Gaming Machine?

Tags: gaming, desktop, windows

I need a good, reliable Windows XP gaming desktop to play games like Need For Speed. My old Pentium D broke, so I am thinking AMD for the processor. 4GB RAM, and a fast SSD. I need discrete graphics. Does anyone have any recommendations of either a prebuild model I can get on eBay or a custom config?
To recap:

CPU: AMD (At least dual core)

RAM: 4GB or greater

GPU: I'm not really proficient with knowledge in this category...

Disk: SSD if possible, SATA

Case: Lots of room for upgrading

If possible, low power components so the PC stays quiet during gaming